# Mixing aggregated initializers with scalar ones in multidimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Is that possible? I would be happy if someone can guide me where in the standard this is mentioned.

For me, it worked as I expect it to behave using `MinGW`. However, I want to know if this is standard or not. This is the code I tested:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int me[3][2] = {{1, 2}, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int x = 0;

    while(x<6) printf("%d_", ((int*)me)[x]), ++x;

    return 0;

}
```

The output is: `1_2_3_4_5_6_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that possible? I would be happy if someone can guide me where in
>   the standard this is mentioned.

I *think* it's standard but I wouldn't say I have definite proof.

> 6.7.9
>
> If the aggregate or union contains elements or members that are
>   aggregates or unions, these rules apply recursively to the
>   subaggregates or contained unions. If the initializer of a
>   subaggregate or contained union **begins with a left brace**, the
>   initializers enclosed by that  brace  and  its  matching  right  brace
>   initialize  the  elements  or  members  of  the subaggregate or the
>   contained union. **Otherwise**, only enough initializers from the list are
>   taken to account for the elements or members of the subaggregate or
>   the ﬁrst member of the contained union; any remaining initializers are
>   left to initialize the next element or member of the aggregate of
>   which the current subaggregate or contained union is a part.

And later, although not specifically for arrays, it gives an example of *inconsistently  bracketed  initialization*:

> ```
> struct { int a[3], b; } w[] = { { 1 }, 2 };
> ```
>
> `w[0].a[0]` is 1 and `w[1].a[0]` is 2; all the other elements are zero

Comment: Yes, it's standard.  The initialisation of `me[0]` is independent of the initialisation of the remaining subaggregates.

Answer (score 2):

As for the initializer, yes that is standard.

As for the printing. Well, that is more complicated. The memory is guaranteed to be continuous, but the compiler can actually trigger UB on that line (but I don't really think that you will find one that does).